# How to call a REST Web API for access token with these cURL commands - in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, curl

I'm a little bit new to OAuth, but learning.  What I have is this tutorial I'm trying to follow.  I'm trying to follow the simple 3-line example under "Bio - retrieving biographical record data": https://members.orcid.org/api/tutorial-retrieve-data-public-api-curl-12-and-earlier

What I need to do though, is use a C# console program to do this instead of CURL, I imagine using the HttpClient namespace.  I have my own client id and client secret to use.  I'm trying to use this public API to get an access token to store wherever, then make calls to get XML data like this example does.  My problem is that I don't know how to convert their CURL calls to C# code.  I'm NOT using an ASP.NET website for this...this all needs to be done in a C# console program.

Comment: Note: Here's the Authorization endpoint I was given: http://devsandbox.orcid.org/oauth/authorize

Comment: And here's the token endpoint: http://api.devsandbox.orcid.org/oauth/token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning on using curl for many different tasks, instead of rewriting the tool. Just download the windows compatible version and embed it as a resource in your console application.

Windows (32 bit) version of curl.exe - [https://akamai.bintray.com/5a/5aa976c1cfc96d95a12cb469ce9bbb1b193ae7599d446f4a22d023a585c5ffe9?**gda**=exp=1455730084~hmac=85d7d80271ecba52893dacb956690dedd020c0ad61f2943b28adcc43ce14e45a&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22curl-7.47.1-win32-mingw.7z%22&response-content-type=application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded](https://akamai.bintray.com/5a/5aa976c1cfc96d95a12cb469ce9bbb1b193ae7599d446f4a22d023a585c5ffe9?__gda__=exp=1455730084~hmac=85d7d80271ecba52893dacb956690dedd020c0ad61f2943b28adcc43ce14e45a&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22curl-7.47.1-win32-mingw.7z%22&response-content-type=application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded)

Edit - Something like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\CURL\curl.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i -L -H 'Accept: application/json' -d 'client_id=APP-GWTDOE3CX89FH7FD' -d 'client_secret=5160c539-4ec9-4e8c-8966-580df68b494f' -d 'scope=/read-public' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://pub.sandbox.orcid.org/oauth/token'";           
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have CURL and was able to pass a command to it.  How do I call it and pass the line to it from C# and get that response back in the code?  I've installed it in my C:\CURL folder.

Comment: I can successfully call CURL via command line, I just need to know how to do in C# to get the XML there.  I'm calling with this: curl https://pub.orcid.org/v1.2/0000-0002-1839-4226/orcid-bio/

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). Using a raw HttpClent seems like a waste when so many good libraries exist.